# ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 255 while installing Kivy on Python 3.8 (Windows)

Tags: python, android, kivy

When I try to install Kivy on python3.8 on Windows10, after a while, python crashes and can not install:

```
Building wheel for kivy (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 255:
```

Comment: You'll need to either set up a working compiler toolchain with python 3.8, or use python 3.7 or earlier, or use Kivy's master branch.

Answer (score 2):

kivy in version 1.11.1 is not compatible with python 3.8. to run with python 3.8 it is necessary to use the version of kivy 2.0 which is not stable and may have errors, to install this version, use this command:

python -m pip install kivy [base] kivy_examples --pre --extra-index-url https://kivy.org/downloads/simple

Comment: This same problem exists on Linux, and the work-around is the same too. Ubuntu 20.04 uses Python 3.8.